# how to fix my counter to correctly print the number of times 2 is inputted?

Tags: java, count, iteration, counter

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grammar
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Ask the user to enter a sentence that uses the word 2 instead of to.
        String theText= "";
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence that uses the word 2 instead of to");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        theText = input.nextLine();
        // Call the method useProperGrammar to process the string according to 
        // the directions.
        System.out.println(useProperGrammar(theText));
        
    }
    
public static String useProperGrammar(String theText)
    {
        String newString="";
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < theText.length(); i++)
        {
        count++;
             if (theText.contains("2"))
            {
            String character = theText.substring(i, i+1);
            newString= theText.replace("2","to");
            System.out.println("Fixed "+ count +" grammatical errors:");
            return newString;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fixed 0 grammatical errors");
                return theText;
            }
        }
        
        return newString;
       
    }

}
```

Basically, I'm trying to count the number of times a user enters '2' and is replaced with
'to' but it always outputs 'Fixed 1 grammatical error' or ('fixed 0 grammatical errors' if there are no '2' entered) no matter how many 2's I enter.

Comment: [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) replaces each substring of the string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement -- so `replace` is invoked only one time and all `2` are replaced with `to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the length something like following

```
int count = theText.length() - theText.replaceAll("2","").length();
```

The replacell method returns the number of times the replacement was done on the string object on which this method is called

complete method

```
public static String useProperGrammar(String theText)
    {
        String newString="";
        for(int i = 0; i < theText.length(); i++)
        {
       
             if (theText.contains("2"))
            {
            int count = theText.length() - theText.replaceAll("2","").length();
            String character = theText.substring(i, i+1);
            newString= theText.replace("2","to");
            System.out.println("Fixed "+ count +" grammatical errors:");
            
            return newString;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fixed 0 grammatical errors");
                return theText;
            }
        }
        
        return newString;
       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grammar {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Ask the user to enter a sentence that uses the word 2 instead of to.
        String theText= "";
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence that uses the word 2 instead of to");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        theText = input.nextLine();
        // Call the method useProperGrammar to process the string according to 
        // the directions.
        System.out.println(useProperGrammar(theText));     
    }
    
    public static String useProperGrammar(String theText){
        String newString="";
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < theText.length(); i++){
             while (theText.contains("2")){
            count = theText.length() - theText.replaceAll("2","").length();
            String character = theText.substring(i, i+1);
            newString= theText.replace("2","to");
            System.out.println("Fixed "+ count +" grammatical errors:");
            return newString;
            }
        
                System.out.println("Fixed 0 grammatical errors");
                return theText;    
        }
        
        return newString;
       
    }

}
```

In addition to the error already reported in the previous answer, your code could not compile, because you wrote an *else* without an *if*.

Comment: you can remove the count++, its not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use charAt function and increase the count every time it returns a '2',
it should be something like this:

```
int count = 0;
String text = "your text 222";
for(int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++){
    if(text.charAt(i) == 2){
    count++;
    }
}
```